# ASP.NET Show HTML hidden field only

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms, hidden-field

ASP.NET on production server sometime show html tag to client. What the problems possible show only html tag to user ?

[image]

Comment: That's `ViewState` hidden field, any code to show why that hidden field rendered in browser? Probably it had sent as string instead of HTML markup.

Comment: This problem occured in input form. I don't have any code to display any user input to client. Are there some characters cause this problem? Or cause of slow internet connection ?

Comment: @Slocky: It has nothing to do with some characters or a slow internet connection. This page is fundamentally messed up. Right click on the page and select view source code, then add that text to your question (no more images). My guess is that it is not valid HTML.